# What are the differences between methods of constructing an object

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the 3 ways of constructing an object:

**1)**

```
LogTreeItem::LogTreeItem(const QList<QVariant>& data, LogTreeItem* parent) :
    m_parentItem {parent}, m_itemData {data}
{
}
```

**2)**

```
LogTreeItem::LogTreeItem(const QList<QVariant>& data, LogTreeItem* parent) :
    m_parentItem (parent), m_itemData (data)
{
}
```

**3)**

```
TreeItem::TreeItem(const QList<QVariant> &data, TreeItem *parent)
{
    m_parentItem = parent;
    m_itemData = data;
}
```

Are they 100% equal? if not, where they differ? what are any advantage/disadvantage associated with each method?

I am guessing some stuff about copy assignment, move constructor or some advanced things in modern c++11 and beyond is getting done in case of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first and second will do the same thing for most types.  However, for types having a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list`, the first will prefer that and the second will prefer an ordinary constructor.  The classic example is `std::vector` with two arguments -- are they two items to put into the vector, or one item with a repetition count.

The third version isn't controlling the construction at all.  As Mateusz correctly notes, the default constructor is used for object creation, and then the value is provided via assignment.  On many types, some parameters can only be set during construction and cannot be changed during assignment, and this method won't work at all.  Also consider references, which must be bound at construction time, and `const` members, which have to be constructed with their final value because assignment is disabled.

Comment: The first constructor, in the event there wasn't an initialiser list, would use list initialisation, which would prevent any narrowing conversions - so would fail to compile if the type of the member was narrower than the parameter

Comment: Although the user didn't mention it, it might be helpful to discuss () vs {} in the context of receiving no arguments, as it's a really crucial difference for aggregate types and primitives.

Comment: @NirFriedman: at least inside the ctor-initializer list, both `x{}` and `x()` will cause value initialization.  Maybe you're thinking of statements, where `X x{};` is an object declaration with a braced initializer, but `X x();` is a function declaration?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah good catch, I got mixed up and thought that `()` was default construction for some reason. My bad!

Answer (score 4):

In the third example, members are first created with default constructor and then copy-assigned.